# WSO2ESB - Securing an API based on registered users or groups

Tags: api, security, wso2-esb

I have implemented a Rest API accessible through WSO2 ESB, and I am trying to secure it using Basic Authentication.

I have already found how to secure the API, using this documentation : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Securing+APIs#SecuringAPIs-BasicAuthUsingaBasicAuthhandler

But here the authentication is based on user information coming from a hard-coded value. I know that I can potentially get the user information from a properties file or something similar.

The question is : is it possible to authenticate the user through a policy or an internal ESB service, to match against the registered users / groups ?

Just like a Proxy Service can be secured through a policy :

```
<proxy name="XXX">
    ...
    <enableSec/>
    <policy key="conf:/policies/policy-xxx.xml"/>
</proxy>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution, based on the WSO2 UserStoreManager, that gives access to both authentication facility and role listing for a user.

Here is the solution : https://github.com/mohanvive/wso2-tools